# Ajax POST FormData not working in https(Secured Link)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, https

We are trying upload pictures to our server. Its working fine in **http** sites, but not in **https** sites.

It throws following:[image] *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)*
Here is the code which is used for ajax

**Java Script**

```
function fnTest(){
var iTaskID = $("#hdnCurTaskID").val();
var files = $("#TaskImg")[0].files;
if (files.length > 0) {
    if (files.length > 3) {
        alert("Maximum 3 files Allowed");
        return;
    }
    if (typeof FormData == "undefined") {
        var postdata = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            postdata.push("UploadedFile", files[i]);
        }
        postdata.push("TaskID", iTaskID);
    }
    else {
        var postdata = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            postdata.append("UploadedFile", files[i]);
        }
        postdata.append("TaskID", iTaskID);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "TaskStatus.asmx/UploadExecTaskPic",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        responseType: "json",
        data: postdata,
        success: function (result) {
            var MaxFile = GetSessionValuecurrent(iTaskID);
            if (MaxFile == "MaxFile") {
                alert("Maximum 3 Files only Allowed to Upload");
            }
            else {

                $("#TaskImg").val("");
                $("#TaskImg").replaceWith($("#TaskImg").clone());
                DoCloseFileSelector();
                DoShowTaskImages(iTaskID, '');
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Upload Error");
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Web Method:**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string UploadExecTaskPic()
{
    string sResult = string.Empty;
    return sResult;
}
```

Comment: What are your server logs saying is the cause of the 500 error? Default location on IIS `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`

Comment: Its says just internal server Error

Comment: You should check the web server logs. That is where you will find out more information on the 500 error. The default location for IIS is %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles

Comment: I will check and update

Comment: Sorry... We are not enabled IIS logs. Checking on server events

Comment: Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/UploadExecTaskPic'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177016/discussion-between-daniel-a-sathish-kumar-and-legenjerry).

Comment: Please see my answer

Comment: yeah.. Marked as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this information in a google search

[FIX Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in](https://web.archive.org/web/20160711020417/http://aspadvice.com:80/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/09/04/FIX-Request-format-is-unrecognized-for-URL-unexpectedly-ending-in.aspx)

> Add the following to web.config since GET and POST are disabled by default in ASP.NET 2.0 and greater:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```